# return true not returning or my else statment isn't working?

Tags: php, methods, if-statement, return

For some reason my else statement is not triggering and i think my method isn't returning true for some reason.

main code

```
function msg($content)
{
   //function that echos out page with content in it
}

$car=new yamiko_car;
if(!$car->add())//returns bool false on fail and true on success
{msg($car->error);}
else{msg('Car has been added');}
```

and the method not it does return false on fail where i test the data but just put a comment there. already tested it all and it worked fine.

```
public function add()
{
    //gets data succesfully

    //MySQL
    $this->query("INSERT INTO car (year, make, model, price, obo, img1, img2, img3, img4, description)
    VALUES ('$year', '$make', '$model', '$price', '$obo', '$img1', '$img2', '$img3', '$img4', 'txt') ");

    echo 'mysql added';
    return true;
}

function query($sql, $result=false)
{
    $query=mysql_query($sql);
    if(!$query){$this->mysqlError.=mysql_error().'<br />';return false;}
    if($result==false){return true;}
    else{return $query;}
}
```

I added the echo statement and it triggers fine...
when there's an error it returns false and runs `msg()`
I switched the statement to `if($car->add()){msg('car added')}else{msg($car->error);}` neither the if or the else statements will trigger
additionally any code after the if statement does not trigger and there is no php or mysql errors.

Comment: your add function returns `true` every time

Comment: `returns bool false on fail and true on success` I don't see when it could return FALSE

Comment: no it doesn't i put comments in there instead of showing all the code for getting and testing the data.

Comment: What does $this->query() exactly do? If some of the code you omitted could be the reason for this behaviour, you should post it here

Comment: you should learn to indent your code properly

Comment: I just posted it and found the problem...my class was extending from my old mysql class that returned the sql result which isn't a bool val...

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like maybe PHP crashes silently, and the interpretation simply stops. Try setting the [PHP error level](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to something like this (in the beginning of the PHP script):

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Comment: Ah, try adding this line as the first line that will be interpreted by PHP. For instance, if you include a `header.php` you need to put the line in top of that file. But if all PHP code is in the same file, it should be enough to put the line below the first `<?php` line.

Comment: I think you get a "session already started" error if there is anything (even spaces or newlines) printed before `session_start()` is called. But I'm not sure, correct me if I'm wrong. I don't know if this could be a clue, given that I don't know about the rest of your code.

Answer (score -1):

I think you missed the parenthesis:

```
$car=new yamiko_car;
```

should be

```
$car=new yamiko_car();
```

Comment: I would have thought they weren't necessary

Comment: not necessary  and if it was, my code would break before getting to the bottom of one of the methods

Comment: Ok, I thought they were necessary - learning never stops. Sorry!